# Does app contain, display, access third party content ( app store review)

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, slcomposeviewcontroller

So I programmed in the SLComposeViewController for Social Framework to add a FB share button. From Google I found the Facebook logo that I used as a UIImage to place on top of the FB share button. When the user clicks on the FB share button there's a link to my app store page. The user can either type a message up or not and click POST to post that message on their Facebook pages. When they post that message they will see my App store page link there too.

Does app contain, display, access third party content
I'm trying to submit my app for review, do I click YES or NO for...

If I click YES then I need to get permission. Who do I get permission from? Google for finding a Facebook logo on their site or Facebook for using their logo to post message to their site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just visit facebook here and read this about how what to do, this will explain what they want YOU to do with branding and HOW their logo should appear, they also give you access to download their own image assets to use, they are very high quality:

https://www.facebookbrand.com/

And no, I doubt your app would qualify you for a YES to the App Store question, I'll have to find some very recent examples of this for you, but I wouldn't worry about this at all for your purposes.

**And for fun and to make sure people see this, here's more brand assets:**

Twitter: https://about.twitter.com/company/brand-assets

Instagram: https://www.instagram-brand.com/

Google: https://developers.google.com/+/branding-guidelines?hl=en and http://gplus-brand.appspot.com/

Apple: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/

Tumblr: https://www.tumblr.com/logo

Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/yt/brand/

Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/about/alien/

Pinterest: https://business.pinterest.com/en/brand-guidelines

LinkedIn: https://brand.linkedin.com/

Yahoo: https://info.yahoo.com/press-center/logos-images

**And how about some Brand asset colors as well:**

http://jgthms.com/social-media-assets/

**And a whole huge list of brand assets:**

http://findguidelin.es/